# Foreign Key Constraint error for delete data form table

Tags: mysql, key

i am doing a project on ONLINE EXAMINATION which is copied from my senior but while execute i got some error. attach my code here and the error msg.

**table #:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question` (
  `testid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qnid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `question` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optiona` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionb` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optiond` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correctanswer` enum('optiona','optionb','optionc','optiond') DEFAULT NULL,
  `marks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`testid`,`qnid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `question`

```
INSERT INTO `question` (`testid`, `qnid`, `question`, `optiona`, `optionb`, `optionc`,     `optiond`, `correctanswer`, `marks`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'why use photoshop', 'image retouching', 'image making', 'image destroying',     'color coreection', 'optiona', 1),
(2, 1, 'java is', 'fish fry', 'software language', 'programing language', 'web maker',     'optionc', 1),
(2, 2, 'what is vaja', 'bengali', 'kokl', 'khsd', 'kojsgf', 'optiona', 1);
```

Table ###

--

### -- Table structure for table `student`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
 `stdid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `stdname` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `stdpassword` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `emailid` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `contactno` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `address` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `city` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `pincode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`stdid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `stdname` (`stdname`),
 UNIQUE KEY `emailid` (`emailid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `studentquestion`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `studentquestion` (
  `stdid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `testid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qnid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `answered` enum('answered','unanswered','review') DEFAULT NULL,
  `stdanswer` enum('optiona','optionb','optionc','optiond') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stdid`,`testid`,`qnid`),
  KEY `testid` (`testid`,`qnid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

```
--
-- Constraints for table `question`
--
ALTER TABLE `question`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `question_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`testid`) REFERENCES `test` (`testid`);

--
-- Constraints for table `studentquestion`
--
ALTER TABLE `studentquestion`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `studentquestion_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`stdid`) REFERENCES `student`     (`stdid`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `studentquestion_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`testid`, `qnid`) REFERENCES     `question` (`testid`, `qnid`);
```

---

**ERROR MESSAGE**

***Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`oes`.`studentquestion`, CONSTRAINT `studentquestion_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`testid`, `qnid`) REFERENCES `question` (`testid`, `qnid`))***

Comment: It seems the table `studentquestion` already have some data in it of which some or all are failing in relation with `question` table. Either `testid` or `qnid` data is mismatching.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is not the full script you have.
Most probably the data is inserted in wrong order. The error occurs because the table `studentquestion` already has the data for the `testid` and `qnid` fields which is not present is the `question` master table. You have to reorder your insert-statements so that master tables are populated first and the detail tables after them.